# How can I save all the information of the training process in tf?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to create a neural network and collect all the possible information just to make comparatives. I'd like to save the loss in each step of the training as well as the time it takes. Every time I run the network, it prints some info messages with this information and I'd like to know how could I save this.

I've created my own model function and set up the configuration.

```
estimator = tf.estimator.Estimator(model_fn=model_fn, config=config)
```

then created the input function and trained it

```
input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
            {"x": x_train[order,:]}, y_train[order],
            batch_size=30, num_epochs=None, shuffle=False)

estimator.train(input_fn=input_fn, max_steps=steps)
```